# Mixed language framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have a framework (let's call it MyKit) written in Objective-C that I'm extending with some Swift classes. I'm trying to get my head around it using this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77

As far as I understand, I'm not supposed to have a bridging header class, and instead put all my includes in the umbrella header file (that I understand to be ).

So I write in MyKit.h:

```
#import <MyKit/ModelObjectA.h>
#import <MyKit/ModelObjectB.h>
#import <MyKit/ControllerObjectC.h>
```

I don't list ControllerObjectD.swift, even though it goes into here as well? Or should I include

```
#import <MyKit/ControllerObjectD-Swift.h>
```

?

ControllerObjectD uses ModelObjectA and ModelObjectB. Now that I don't have a bridge headerfile, I get compile errors in it because it cannot find these objects.

The documentation says "Swift will see every header you expose publicly in your umbrella header." and this is true when I import the framework into other projects, but the framework project cannot compile because it doesn't see it. I have turned on the "Define Modules" build setting.

Is there something I've misunderstood about the umbrella header, perhaps? Where can I say "hi project, this is the umbrella header file"? The framework compiles if I set the umbrella header file as bridging header, but that sounds like I've come back to the beginning this way?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe your problem may be down to the Access Modifiers in your Swift class, however I've written a short guide and sample project to help you:

Sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/elliott-minns/SwiftObjCTestFramework)

There are two parts to having a mixed language framework:

1. Importing Objective-C into Swift
2. Importing Swift into Objective-C

---

## 1. Importing Objective-C into Swift

This is, for example, if you have an Objective-C class named `Player` that you want to add to a swift class called `Game`.

According to the documentation, you need to do these two steps to import the `Player` object into the `Game` object.

1. Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module setting for that framework target is set to Yes.

[image: Defines Module]

2. In your umbrella header file, import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift.

   ```
   #import <Framework/Player.h>
   ```

Make sure your `Player` header file in Objective-C is marked for public target membership in the framework:

[image: Public Header File Setting]

Following these steps, it's possible to import the `Player` Objective-C class into the `Game` Swift Class:

```
import UIKit

public class Game: NSObject {
    public let player: Player

    public init(player: Player) {
        self.player = player
        super.init();
    }
}
```

---

## 2. Importing Swift into Objective-C

For importing the Swift `Game` class into the `Player` object, we can follow a similar procedure.

1. As before; Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module setting for that framework target is set to Yes.

[image: Defines Module]

2. Import the Swift code from that framework target into any Objective-C .m file within that framework target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate names:

   ```
   #import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
   ```

   In my case, this works as:

   ```
   #import <SwiftObjC/SwiftObjC-Swift.h>
   ```

   and I assume, for you:

   ```
   #import <MyKit/MyKit-Swift.h>
   ```

   Therefore, make sure that all the properties, methods and classes you want to access are defined as public in your swift file or else they won't be visible to Objective-C .

I have uploaded my sample project showing how this all works on GitHub https://github.com/elliott-minns/SwiftObjCTestFramework

I hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: After a half day of 'trial n error' and browsing for solution.This is the most properly explained answer.Which has helped me,thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to make classes visible to Swift without exposing them in the umbrella header? I have some internal classes that I don't want to expose to the users of the framework, but then I can't access them in the new Swift classes.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do this. I've not yet managed to find a way.

Comment: Yes you can. You need to define a private submodule and import that submodule in your Swift code.

Comment: need to make header file in Objective-C mark as public target membership in the framework, this is what I need to know, thanks!!

Comment: Above example covers only Public classes. If you have private classes, you consider below example - https://github.com/danieleggert/mixed-swift-objc-framework

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to do the exact same thing with a cocoa touch static library?

Comment: when importing Swift into Objective-C, is possible to avoid swift classes from being public?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do bridging-header to access your obj-c code in swift.
More in the link
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

so it is a file with your imports from obj-c transfering to swift. names are very important so care about that. hope it helps

p.s. also you need to add this header path to your project settings

Comment: Bridging-headers are not allowed in framework-targets. Though I would love to know why.

Answer (score 1):

From the Documentation at Apple: A Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class to be accessible and usable in Objective-C. For more information about what you can access from Objective-C and how the Swift interface is imported, see Swift Type Compatibility.

So your public swift class needs to extend NSObject for example.