# Mixed language framework with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm creating Swift framework that will be distributed via Cocoapods. Inside MyFramework I use few frameworks installed via Cocoapods. Importing frameworks written in swift works fine, but I get trouble importing objc framework. I want to use CardIO inside MyFramework and add it as pods submodule, so user can optionally install it like pod 'MyFramework/CardIO'. After installing CardIO pod in MyFramework, I try to import it in MyFramework-umbrella-header like:
`#import "CardIO/CardIO.h"`
but get the error:
`"Include of non-modular header inside framework module "`.
I also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760966/mixed-language-framework?answertab=active#tab-top), but this doesn’t work when importing objc framework. Any idea is it possible to import objc framework that installed via Cocoapods to Swift framework?

Answer (score 1):

[FIXED]: The problem was in CardIO podspec, they import only .h files as source_files. So after including .m files to source files: `.source_files = 'CardIO/*.{h,m}'` Cocoapods generate CardIO modulemap, then it's possible to import CardIO module in Swift framework.

Comment: Hi @SpartaqUA, I'm having the same issue you described. I forked the repo and updated the podspec as you suggested. But when I import `#import "CardIO.h"` on my framework, I get the error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module". Is that how you imported CardIO on your framework? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I have now changed to `import CardIO` on my Swift file but now getting a different error. `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CardScannerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
`. Can you please share the link of your forked repo? I'd like to have a look at the podspec file. Maybe there are other changes?

Comment: Hi @RaphaelOliveira, I create my own [Dynamic Wrapper](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CardIOSDK) around CardIO. Also you can check [here](https://github.com/verygoodsecurity/vgs-collect-ios) example of swift framework that use the CardIO wrapper. Please note that there could be issues with Xcode12 arm64 architecture support, so I would suggest to test it with Xcode11.x first.